# how to implement a multi-tenant configuration solution in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, devops

One common pattern I've seen in many applications is [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy). Basically, I'm configuring an application that has some of its configuration values which are different based on the country. The way I've managed to do this configuration is basically using a "partners" dictionary in yaml:

```
---
partners:
    us: 
        url: 'http://company.com'
    uk: 
        url: 'http://company.co.uk'
    fr: 
        url: 'https://company.fr'
    ch: 
        url: 'https://company.fr'
```

And thus, when serving customers which are identified to come from 'us' we'll use one value for url that will be different if the application identifies it as coming from 'fr'.

Then, when configuring with a template, I do something similar to:

```
template:  xxxx
with_items: partners_list
```

Then, in the template I use `partners[item].url` to access the variable. Thus, with one template, I'm configuring multiple files with different values according to the partner. Bear into account that most of the values are common though (most configurations are not in the partners dict).

This is less than satisfactory.

What I would like to have is a "dynamic variables" system to implement something similar to a "context". Like, something simple and portable that loads contexts into your main namespace. So something that allows me to simply reference "url" and it will automatically try to use `partners[item].url` and if it's not there, use plain `url`.

One solution would be to use `partners[item].url | default(url)`, but this is very verbose and leads to a bit of confusion IMHO. I'd rather not add so much clutter in the templates.

Another possibility would be something like `"{% set_context 'us' %}" // "{% end_context %}"` in jinja and then overlap the variables in the dict with first level variables, with a context. I think that would be satisfactory as well. Problem is, can I extend jinja in a way that can be put in my repo, without needing to touch everyone's ansible/jinja installations? In other words, can I choose another templating engine in ansible, so I can write an extended jinja (which is able to lookup for variables) that ansible would use?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a group in your Ansible inventory for each "partner" and set your *url* variable in the group_vars for that group.

IE in groups_vars/uk_partner.yml:

```
name: uk
url: 'http://company.co.uk'
```

Then you would need to create logical hosts for each group and run your play against that list of hosts.

In inventory.yml:

```
all:
  children:
    uk_partner:
      hosts:
        - uk-webserver
        - uk-db-server
```

You would also need to hard code the *ansible_host* variable in *host_vars* for these logical hosts, or add DNS names for them.

IE in host_vars/uk-webserver.yml:

```
ansible_host: 192.0.2.4
```

Then in host_vars/us-webservers.yml:

```
ansible_host: 192.0.2.4
```

(Given that 192.0.2.4 is the address of a web server shared between these partners.)

In your play:

```
- hosts: "uk-webserver,us-webserver"
  tasks:
    - name: do webserver things to multiple partners
```

...

Then in your template you could reference {{ url }} without qualification as it would be resolved appropriately per group.

These "partner" specific hosts would simply be logical iterations of the real hosts associated with those partners, regardless of whether "partners" live on shared infrastructure with other "partners".

You could manually add these to your inventory, or if that would be impractical due to the scale of partners and infrastructure, a simple dynamic inventory script could generate them based on your list of partners. In some cases you could also use the [*add_host*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module to generate them in a play.

Remember when using add_host, it's necessary to explicitly add the host to every group you want it to be a member of. In my experience it will not inherit parent group membership when added to a child group.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your partners dictionary into a list of hashes you can accomplish what you're looking for. This is the way I accomplish multi-tenancy in an application I support. Here's one approach with your example:

```
partners:
  - name: us 
    url: 'http://company.com'
  - name: uk
    url: 'http://company.co.uk'
  - name: fr 
    url: 'https://company.fr'
  - name: ch 
    url: 'https://company.fr'
```

Render the template:

```
template:  xxxx
with_items: partners
```

Now you can reference the site url via `item.url` in your template.

Comment: Actually I didn't say it, but the main target is to use plain `url`. From `item.url` to `partners[item].url` there's not such a big difference. What I don't want is to have to change the template if I decide to move one variable out of the `partners` dict. That's why I was focusing on using "url" which will lookup inside `partners` and outside if it fails.